# Can not connect Postgresql to DOcker-compose

Tags: postgresql, powershell, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

Using docker-compose I'm trying to create a database, I thought perhaps I have another superuser for that error, but when checking

postgres=# `\du`

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

 # Backend API
    smart-brain-api:
        container_name: backend
        build: ./
        command: npm start
        working_dir: /usr/src/smart-brain-api
        # environment:
        #     POSTGRES_USER: test1
        #     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test2
        #     POSTGRES_DB: smart-brain-docker
        #     POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
            # POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        # links:
        #     - postgres
        ports:
            - "3001:3001"
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/smart-brain-api

 # Postgres
    postgres:
        # environment:
            # POSTGRES_USER: test1
            # POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test2
            # POSTGRES_DB: smart-brain-docker
            # POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
            # POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
```

The commented out stuff is what I use further in the file, and additionally by me: `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust` the suggested stuff - no success.

I also tried changing `POSTGRES_HOST:` to `postgres1` - in case it interfere with my superuser postgres - no success.

I even tried changing `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to my actual superuser username and password.

And this is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/smart-brain-api

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The **error** after `docker-compose up --build`

```
Successfully tagged smart-brain-api_smart-brain-api:latest
Creating postgres ... done
Creating backend ... done                                                                                         
Attaching to backend, postgres
postgres           | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
postgres           |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
postgres           |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
postgres           |
postgres           |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
postgres           |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
postgres           |
postgres           |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
postgres           |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
postgres exited with code 1
backend            |
```

I also noticed when I ignored this error, and went further I would **only** get `CREATE DATABASE` by `postgres_1`

While in the course he is getting:

```
...
CREATE DATABASE
CREATE ROLE
...
```

Also I use `-L` for nodemon in `package.json` (not sure if that helps in finding the issue, I only HAD to use it as it wouldn't read my new changes).

When I simply type `psql` it tries to let me login with username of my windows (which is not set as postgres user) so I must use `psql -U postgres` to login, is that "default" user causing some problems to the superuser?

I will keep trying differen and report back.

Comment: Nobody knows if i miss smtg??

Comment: If you only include POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_DB, and POSTGRES_PASSWORD it doesn’t work?

Comment: @Carlos actually it doesn't help,

Comment: You get the same error?

Comment: @Carlos yes I do, I was thinking of removing my pgAdmin master password (but that's not "superuser initializing")?


Next what error came to me is:
https://i.imgur.com/lcV282h.png


Which used to pop-up before i set `-L` (legacyWatch) in `package.json` to nodemon.
Now it pops up again with postgres, can you help me connect the dots/ where else may I use -L for 'pg'?

Comment: If you remove the backend service does the Postgres service come up or do you get the same error?

Comment: @Carlos, if I use `postgres=# CREATE USER sally WITH PASSWORD 'secret';
CREATE ROLE` and i `exit`, and try to login to sally: ```> psql -U sally
Password for user sally:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "sally"```

Comment: Sorry but based on your comments I’m not really sure what is really the error you are getting.  Based on your original posted log it looks like your postgres service isn’t coming up correctly and that should be something simple to fix based on your posted compose file it would probably be the environment setting I mentioned in previous comment.